# SQLite Autoincrement ignores explicit ID's

Tags: c#, sqlite

According to the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

However, when this is put into practice, any explicitly given ID is overwritten on an `Insert`: (Full code sample provided, just copy & paste into a Console App and add the Sqlite package & sqlite3.dll.)

```
public class SqliteDatabase
{
    string DatabasePath = string.Empty;
    SQLiteConnection SqlCon;

    public SqliteDatabase()
    {
        DatabasePath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "sqliteDB.sqlite3");
        CreateDatabase();
    }

    void CreateDatabase()
    {
        SqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath);
        //Ensure we always have a clean start
        SqlCon.DropTable<DatabaseObjectModel>();
        SqlCon.CreateTable<DatabaseObjectModel>();
    }

    public void CreateIDIfNotExists()
    {
        //Explicitly set the ID:
        var object1 = new DatabaseObjectModel()
        {
            ID = 10,
            Name = "ObjectWithOwnID"
        };

        var object2 = new DatabaseObjectModel()
        {
            Name = "ObjectWithoutOwnID"
        };

        //Insert objects
        SqlCon.Insert(object1);
        SqlCon.Insert(object2);

        foreach(DatabaseObjectModel dom in SqlCon.Table<DatabaseObjectModel>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} | ID: {1}", dom.Name, dom.ID));
        }
    }
}

public class DatabaseObjectModel
{
    //Integer primary key, with auto-increment set to ON.
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Name: ObjectWithOwnID | ID: 1
Name: ObjectWithoutOwnID | ID: 2
```

But according to the documentation, `ObjectWithOwnID` should keeps its explicit ID of '10'?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, or is this a bug?

Comment: The documentation explains how the INSERT statement in SQL works. There is no such statement in your code.

Comment: Think this is might be me being naive that the Sqlite ORM would work on the same way!